# Disable a certificate in the Root using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

Using Windows Server Core.

I want to disable a certificate in the store root's folder. I have the thumbprint of the certificate that I want to disable and as per the picture below I can do it via the Windows UI. But I want to do it via Powershell.

I couldn't find how to disable a certificate via PowerShell, do you know how?

N.B. I am not interested in deleting the certificate

If you are curious, this is a solution to the problem that is discussed here:
https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9774/2238/incomplete-certificate-chain-on-windows-servers

[image]

Comment: did you check https://superuser.com/questions/748402/is-there-a-way-to-quickly-disable-all-trusted-root-certificates-in-windows-7 ?

Comment: @MickyBalladelli I don't want to remove then add at a later time, I specifically want to disable (to reserve the place for the certificate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to call unmanaged [CertSetCertificateContextProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376573(v=vs.85).aspx) unmanaged function by using p/invoke interop and passing ASN-encoded empty X509 EKU extension value (which is two bytes, `0x30` and `0x0`) to explicitly disable EKUs in the property.

The code would look like this:

```
# define unmanaged function interop signatures
$signature = @"
[DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool CertSetCertificateContextProperty(
    IntPtr pCertContext,
    uint dwPropId,
    uint dwFlags,
    IntPtr pvData
);
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct CRYPTOAPI_BLOB {
    public uint cbData;
    public IntPtr pbData;
}
"@
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Namespace PKI -Name Crypt32
# create empty X509 EKU extension value. Empty value literally disables all EKU
$bytes = New-Object byte[] -ArgumentList 2
$bytes[0] = 48
$bytes[1] = 0
# do unmanaged stuff
$pbData = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::AllocHGlobal(2)
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::Copy($bytes, 0, $pbData, 2)
# fill pvData structure
$blob = New-Object PKI.Crypt32+CRYPTOAPI_BLOB -Property @{
    cbData = 2;
    pbData = $pbData;
}
# do more unmanaged stuff
$pvData = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::AllocHGlobal([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf([type][PKI.Crypt32+CRYPTOAPI_BLOB]))
# copy data value to unmanaged memory
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::StructureToPtr($blob, $pvData, $false)
# call CertSetCertificateContextProperty function
[PKI.Crypt32]::CertSetCertificateContextProperty($Cert.Handle,9,0,$pvData)
# release unmanaged memory to prevent memory leak
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FreeHGlobal($pbData)
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FreeHGlobal($pvData)
```

Note that function call requires valid X509Certificate2 certificate object in `$cert` variable.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this one. Yes it worked.